# Running mahout kmeans on hadoop multi node cluster

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am running kmeans on a multinode cluster.The input size is about 100mb and I have modified bin/mahout file like this

> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.min.split.size=10MB"
>
> .
>
> .
>
> MAHOUT_OPTS="$MAHOUT_OPTS -Dmapred.map.tasks=10"

Over each iteration i get

> 12/09/12 17:05:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Launched map tasks=1
>
> 12/09/12 17:05:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=6
>
> 12/09/12 17:05:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=1

Does this mean that it runs on single node instead of multi node?And if so what do I miss in the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you want to set the max split size rather than min, if you want more splits. It is still only a suggestion to the cluster.